# MS Visual Studio and BI : Issue with tables relationships

Tags: visual-studio-2010, business-intelligence

i'm on a graduating project, and it's about BI !

I first of all created my cubes models under Visual Paradigm, i did the relationships like usually, and everything was perfect.
Then i exported the model(constellation model) to an SQL Server 2012 database, and the relationships were still there (as you can see below).
[image]

So i created a BI project, and set the last database as a data source, but when i created the data source view (which appears as a diagram), some relationships disappeared (like shown below), all the (dimension) tables on the top of the picture are not connected !
[image]

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem concerns specifically some tables cause i used tinyint as a type for the primary keys of these tables, and for some reasons that i don't know MSS didn't accept this data type !

Anyways, i've changed it to smallint and now it's working perfectly.